# Can't upload updates with Transporter (MacOS) for a specific app (IOS)

Tags: ios, certificate

Every time I try to upload an updated build of my app, "Marées NC," with the Bundle ID `nc.cocogeek.mareesNC`, I'm getting this error:

```
Asset validation failed (90035)
Invalid Signature. A sealed resource is missing or invalid. The file at path “Marees NC.app/Marees NC” is not properly signed. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate".
```

I've tried multiple times with the `Distribution` certificate, and have even created new certificates.

I'm able to successfully upload new builds for a different app, but not for my app, however I'm using the same certificate (which expires on Dec 22, 2023) with both apps.

Is this Apple's issue or is it a problem on my end? I've already tried creating new certificates and provisioning files, but I still got this error.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the problem is the spaces in the name of the app bundle etc. Traducteur is a single word. Marees NC is not.

Comment: Hmm thx for the answer but I don't think that's that. App ID : "MareesNC" vs "Traducteur". I'll try to change the Name of the APP to MareesNC and let you know

Comment: I"ve replaced    `<filename>Marees NC</filename>` with `<filename>MareesNC</filename>` in my xml. Nothing changed.. Still same error